# Remove li from ul using id of li

Tags: javascript, html

I have drop down where options are in li. I want to dynamically remove li with specific id. Structure is like below

```
<ul class="es-list" style="top: 305.483px; left: 191.25px; width: 194px; display: block;">

    <li id="from_7" class="" value="7" style="display: block;">Adelaide</li>
    <li id="from_1" class="" value="1" style="display: block;">Alexandria</li>
    <li id="from_17" class="" value="17" style="display: block;">Antwerp</li>
    <li id="from_19" value="19" style="display: block;">Aqaba</li>
```

I tried like

```
$('#from_7').remove();
```

but it is not removing li

Comment: chk browser console for errors, because its working fine on my side

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o7ydpp2w/ Working fine dude

Comment: Do you have multiple li with id `#from_7`?

Comment: devpro no error in console

Comment: Rajesh I checked id are unique

Comment: try with document.ready

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must need to check browser console for errors and i think you are missing the jQuery library file in your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from_7').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="es-list" style="top: 305.483px; left: 191.25px; width: 194px; display: block;">

<li id="from_7" class="" value="7" style="display: block;">Adelaide</li>
<li id="from_1" class="" value="1" style="display: block;">Alexandria</li>
<li id="from_17" class="" value="17" style="display: block;">Antwerp</li>
<li id="from_19" value="19" style="display: block;">Aqaba</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you might add the `<li>` elements dynamically via JS/jQuery. If that's the case then please change your line to

```
$('body #from_7').remove();
```

Also make sure that you have the jQuery plugin included in the page.

The reason for this behaviour is that whenever you add items dynamically on a page (e.g. you add `<li>` items via JS in an empty `<ul>` which existed when the page loaded ) then the selector must be:

```
$('<name of any parent which existed when page loaded> <actual element selector, in your case is ID of element>');
```

I added **body** as **parent** of your **li**, because that's always one parent which existed when page loaded.

**Later edit:**

Try adding this command inside document.ready(), and **ONLY** after the element have been added for sure. Do not execute it before the element was added, because nothing will happen.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        // code that adds `<li>`


        // other code...

        // remove your targeted LI element only when you press on any LI, and ONLY after its been added to the list
        $('body ul.es-list').on('click','li', function(){
              $('body ul.#from_7').remove();
        })
  });
```

Comment: @hrishi Open developer tools (F12), select console tab, and check for errors there. Write here if there is any.

Comment: Yes drop down options are generated dynamically it is editable select drop down. But solution is not working for me

Comment: @hrishi Also, as devpro already answered, try wrapping the remove command in $(document).ready(function(){   $('#from_7').remove();   });

Comment: I am calling it from ajax success which is in function. In ajax success I get the id to be removed

Comment: @hrishi please add the AJAX code that fills this <ul> with elements, including the line where you remove the li, and we might help you.

Comment: I load drop down using                                                                  window.onload = function ()
        {
                     $('#select_select').editableSelect();        
        }

Comment: At the time of page load all values are displayed in drop down and on button click I call ajax call which get id from database and I am trying to remove it from ajax success

Comment: @hrishi I see that you are using editableSelect plugin. Try using their methods to remove an LI element. $('#select_select').editableSelect('remove', 0); // to remove element on index 0

Comment: Thank you all. It is working with $('#from_7').remove(); S orry the value I was testing was present in database two times so I did not recognize it is deleting.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Comment: I tried  document.getElementById("from_7").remove(); it is showing document.getElementById(...) is null in console